# When using joiner transformation flat files and relational table ,mapping success but no data loaded in target and source table truncated

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I used joiner transformation.my source was on flat file(csv) and table.both contain data.but after joiner transformation shows status succeeded.but no data loaed in target and my relational table(source table) is empty now.

```
i checked the following
datatypematching
flat file path
everything was correct.
```

2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_2_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : DBG_21077 : DBG_21077 Create joiner cache on master relation : (Sun Aug 27 19:25:16 2017)
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_2_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : TE_7212 : Increasing [Index Cache] size for transformation [JNR_01] from [17886685] to [17888000].
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_2_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : TE_7212 : Increasing [Data Cache] size for transformation [JNR_01] from [35773370] to [35773712].
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_2_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : CMN_1690 : Created new data file [C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\Cache\PMJNR94_5_0_130.dat] and index file [C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\Cache\PMJNR94_5_0_130.idx] for Joiner [JNR_01].
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_2_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : DBG_21214 : DBG_21214 Finished joiner cache on master relation : (Sun Aug 27 19:25:16 2017)
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : DBG_21273 : Joiner transform : JNR_01

2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : CMN_1103 : WARNING : No row found from the master relation. Joiner will not produce any output row.
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : DBG_21603 : DBG_21603 Open master relation cache for detail joiner : (Sun Aug 27 19:25:16 2017)
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : DBG_21215 : DBG_21215 Finished processing detail relation : (Sun Aug 27 19:25:16 2017)
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : CMN_1795 : The index cache size that would hold [0] input rows from the master for [JNR_01], in memory, is [0] bytes
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : CMN_1794 : The data cache size that would hold [0] input rows from the master for [JNR_01], in memory, is [536] bytes
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : WRT_8167 : Start loading table [TGT_PROD] at: Sun Aug 27 19:25:16 2017
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : WRT_8168 : End loading table [TGT_PROD] at: Sun Aug 27 19:25:16 2017
2017-08-27 19:25:16 : INFO : (1184 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | Int) : node01_etl : WRT_8035 : Load complete time: Sun Aug 27 19:25:16 2017

## LOAD SUMMARY

WRT_8036 Target: TGT_PROD (Instance Name: [TGT_PROD])
WRT_8044 No data loaded for this target

Comment: Sounds like something independent of the joiner i.e. the joiner didnt find any rows as the table was empty by that time. We'll need more logs from the start of the session to identify what happened. What you can check is how many rows were read from each source in the load summary

Comment: Check the data that you're trying to join. It appears as if nothing was matching between the two sources. You can try to change the logging on the joiner or use 'Collect performance data' session property to check where did all the rows end up.